# Significance of the dirty joke at the end of Kingsman

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

The movie was great, however, the last dirty joke about queen's favor to main character for rescuing her seemed completely random. What was the intention of it, what would it signify?

Comment: I AGREE! I'm really open minded but that was just kind of disgusting.  Glad to hear that someone else had the same reaction!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From an interview with Matthew Vaughn (director)

> It ends [on that joke] for a very strong reason. A lot of Bond movies used to end on things like Bond trying to ‘attempt re-entry,’ or ‘keeping the British end up.’ So I just thought, ‘We’ve pushed the boundary on every sort of spy cliché.’ We’ve got to end it on The Big One. And there’s only one way of doing it, taking it to the next level!